# Delete table row with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Currently I have a table for information called episodes. The table has fields consisting of title, air date, episode number, and plot. I use javascript to clone the fields and also to delete them. My problem is the delete function deletes only the title, airdate, and episode number; however the plot box remains. The problem from what I can tell is that the plot is wrapped in a different `<tr></tr>` tag. How do I get the delete function to delete both sets?

Here is the table

```
<table id="template" style="display: none">
<tr class="line">
    <td width="50%">
    <label><?php _e('Episode Title'); ?></label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="episode_title[]" id="episode_title[]" value="" class="title regular-text" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>    
    </td>

    <td width"10%">        
    <label><?php _e('Airdate'); ?></label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="episode_airdate[]" id="episode_airdate[]" value="" class="airdate regular-text" style="width:100%" />
    </p>
    </td>

     <td width="10%">        
    <label><?php _e('Season:'); ?></label>
    <p>
          <?php

            for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
                $season_nums[]=$i;

            echo '<select name="episode_season[]" select id="episode_season[]" class="season regular-text" style="100%">';
                echo '<option value="">' . __("Season" ) . '</option>';
                foreach($season_nums as $season_num){
                    $selected = '';
                    echo '<option value="' . $season_num . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $season_num . '</option>';
                }
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
    </p>
    </td>

    <td width="10%">        
    <label><?php _e('Episode:'); ?></label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="episode_number[]" id="episode_number[]" value="" class="number regular-text" style="width: 100%" />
    </p>
    </td>



    <td width="10%" class="commands">
        <a rel="delete" class="button">-</a> <a rel="add" class="button">+</a>
    </td>


</tr>

<tr class="line2"> 
   <td width="100%">       
    <label><?php _e('Plot:'); ?></label>
      <textarea name="episode_plot[]" id="episode_plot[]" class="plot regular-text"value="" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4" ><?php echo $_POST['episode_season'] ?></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
        // Delete the "-" button in first row
    $('#attachments tr:first-child .commands a[rel="delete"]').remove();
}

function items_add()
{
    obj = $('#template tr').clone().appendTo('#attachments');
    lines++;

    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        options = arguments[0];

        $('.title', obj).val( options.title );
        $('.airdate',   obj).val( options.airdate );
        $('.season',   obj).val( options.season );
        $('.number',   obj).val( options.number );
        $('.plot',   obj).val( options.plot );
    }
}

$('#attachments').delegate('.commands a', 'click', function()
{
    var action = $(this).attr('rel');
    var confirm_delete = true;

    // Add action
    if ('add' == action) {
        items_add();
    }

    // Delete action
    if ('delete' == action) {
        // La TR en la tabla
        var oTr = $(this).parent().parent();
        var episode_name = $('.title', oTr).val();
        var episode_airdate = $('.airdate', oTr).val();
        var episode_season = $('.season', oTr).val();
        var episode_number  = $('.number', oTr).val();
        var episode_plot  = $('.plot', oTr).val();


        if (episode_name != '' || episode_number != '' || episode_plot != '') {
            if ( !confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + episode_name + '?') ) {
                confirm_delete = false;
            }
        }

        if (confirm_delete) {
            oTr.remove();
            lines--;
        }
    }
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    items_init();
});

})(jQuery);
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: it would be easier if you showed the generated html markup and not the php markup.

Comment: Did you try to change `oTr.remove();` to `oTr.next().remove(); oTr.remove();`?

Comment: Have you thought about using IDs? Adding say r_###_one and r_###_two to your rows (where ### = your numeric ID) then you can just split on that id and use it for deleting both at once. `$('#r_'+id+'_one').remove();` etc...

Comment: @Yaypaul I Like that idea, I might implement it to prevent further troubles, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
var oTr = $(this).parent().parent();
```

to

```
var oTr = $(this).closest("tr");
```

Then use `oTr.remove()`

Answer (score 1):

IDEA:

in php generate a random number like

```
$rand = time() * rand();
```

echo it on the line rows

```
<tr class="line" data-row="<?php echo $rand; ?>">
```

and

```
<tr class="line2" data-row="<?php echo $rand; ?>">
```

Using your delete function when someone clicks the link

```
var oTr = $(this).closest("tr");
var data-row =$(oTr).attr('data-row');
 $('tr[data-row=' + data-row + ']').remove();
```

the idea is have a unique string to identify tr with line and line2 classes

Comment: Pretty much my comment above but using data- attributes. It will work just as good, unless you need to target an individual tr directly for some other process, then the ID route may help you more. @Craig